# Where did /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf go?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, touchpad, mac

On my Macbook I can only move the cursor while also pressing the touchpad after a default install. A per login session fix is to run "synclient FingerLow=10" and "synclient FingerHigh=20".

In order to make this change permanent I'm [supposed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook4-1/Lucid) to do add the following in the tochpad section of `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf`. **But I do not have this file.**

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "FingerLow" "10"
    Option "FingerHigh" "20"
EndSection
```

#### Where do I need to apply this change?

Comment: which version Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: is there any `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj 12.04.4

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes. I'll try to put it in here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The description says that one should copy the contents to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first to make this change persistent over updates. But the xorg.conf.d doesn't exist.

Comment: `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"`

Comment: you have to copy and rename the file,i think.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, this solution worked. Thanks :)

Comment: may i post it as an answer?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Of course, I'm waiting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook4-1/Lucid) says, you have to edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` file.But the lines inside that file says,

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
```

So don't do that.Just copy the contents and then rename this file into `xorg.conf.d` and it looks like  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`.Now place the below lines on that file and save it.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "FingerLow" "10"
    Option "FingerHigh" "20"
EndSection
```

Comment: Edit my answer, if there is any error.

Comment: I did copy the file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and edited it and renamed it there but it did *not* give me the same result as editing it directly. Some settings from the original still persist. I'm confused. Guess I'll just edit the original then.