# How do I enable horizontal scroll on lubuntu desktop

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed with the Lubuntu desktop installed. On the Ubuntu desktop two finger horizontal scrolling works fine but when I log into my preferred lubuntu desktop two finger scrolling only works with vertical scrolling and I cannot find an option to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The setting should be:

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

if you have a Synaptics touchpad. To make the changes permanent, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/431301/158442).

Comment: I get the message 'Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?'. I am on Lubuntu 17.04