# Google Chrome touchscreen - right-click gets stuck

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, touchscreen

I'm having some problems with Google Chrome and my touchscreen in Ubuntu 14.04.

Basic touchscreen usage works fine, but if I double-tap on the touchscreen (the gesture for a right-click, as far as I can tell), then every time I touch the screen after that, it acts as if I've right-clicked.

This problem appears to be unique to Chrome; xterm, for example, acts normally.

Any suggestions?

Is there a way to get touchscreen events to act identically to mouse events? For example, I found where I can disable touch events (using `chrome://flags/#touch-events`), but that completely disables tap for left click.

Is anyone successfully using a touchscreen with Google Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04? (I'm working on this for a kiosk-style setup, so I'm using Ubuntu Server and nodm instead of Unity or another desktop shell, and my hardware's a little unusual also.)

Comment: I'm running full Ubuntu 14.04 with normal hardware, but having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using xev to see what the actions end up as, don't know how it works for touch though. See www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml

Comment: @DaveM - We tried `xev` and couldn't see anything that would indicate the problem.

Comment: @JoshKelley you likely need to run it before and after the problem arises, so as to get the base point and the fault. Otherwise I see you have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least one possible solution that worked for me. :)

That problem could be solved for me with Chrome's `--touch-devices` command line parameter.

Determine X's input device id in a console by

```
xinput list
```

leading to

```
google-chrome --touch-devices=10
```

on my system.

To make Chrome always use this CLI flag, see:

[How to set CLI flags for Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78638/how-to-set-cli-flags-for-google-chrome)

[Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04)

Comment: We'd stumbled on `--touch-devices` while investigating another issue and didn't realize it could help here as well. I'm not in a position right now to test if this fixes the problems we were having, but it makes sense; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very elusive for me so I'm not sure if my current fix will actually stay fixed. But what I did was to comment out any occurrence of `Option "SoftButtonAreas"` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`. However, this is not the way to do it. Rather I [should](https://askubuntu.com/a/431301/81166) override this file in something like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/my-synaptics.conf`. I'll reboot and see if that breaks it again...